# What ubuntu/linux version of software can i use?

Tags: system-installation

I am a python programer, and have been working on windows 8.1 and 10 for a while, but after a bit of research i think i want to switch to some ubuntu/linux software, which one should i use?

Comment: The one at http://www.ubuntu.com/download seems fairly popular. Try it. It's free.

Comment: Why not try it before you install (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0)  Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format, so 19.10 is from 2019-October, 18.04 from 2018-April etc...  LTS releases are long-term-support release so have longer lives (eg. I'd not recommend 19.04 as it's approaching the end of it's supported life, requiring users to bump to the next 19.10 release..; LTS releases can bump to the next LTS release)..   As for which flavor - that's a personal thing on you can decide..  ie. which desktop on the Ubuntu base best suits your tastes & workflows..

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours  if you want to try Ubuntu flavors, which you can also try before you install (see prior link)   *Also note: LTS flavors have 3 years of supported life, unlike main Ubuntu; myself I'd still go for a flavor as GNOME isn't my cup-of-tea but only you can decide which you prefer; just like you might prefer `emacs` over `vim` (or hate them both), prefer spaces to tabs etc*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release) and [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407/)

Comment: Are you talking about distros, Ubuntu flavours, or programs? Please [edit] to clarify. BTW welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good choice to start as new working with Linux, is a Long Term Support (LTS) release of Ubuntu. The main reason to use a LTS release is you will have support for 5 years from the launch time. And Ubuntu is nice because it is based on Debian architecture, and is more comfortable to use for people that are used to working on Windows.

So, my advice for you is:
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS