# Why Ubuntu.com doesn't suggest getting Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: 18.04, 19.04, versions

I currently have **Ubuntu 18.04** installed and recently discovered **Ubuntu 19.04** already released. But when I get to https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop it suggests downloading Ubuntu 18.04. Why not 19.04?

Comment: 18.04 is a "Long Term Support Release", 19.04 is not, see: [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release) Also note that 19.04 is already past its support period by now.

Comment: @pomsky yes, thank you, didn't know it's every 2 years.

Comment: http://ubuntu-news.org/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/   (provided as FYI only)