# Can I update from ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 (when 22.04 will be released)?

Tags: updates, 21.10

I want to install ubuntu on my pc and I want to have the new 22.04 version.

Will I be able to upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 after the release? (Or should I install 22.04 beta now?)

Comment: Keep in mind that adopting Ubuntu 22.04 early may lead to an unstable system. For this reason, it’s recommended to test out the new operating system on a virtual machine or test machine, until the official release date.

Comment: But can i update from 21.10 to 22.04?

Comment: Why do you want to early upgrade to 22.04? It is not at all stable, this is not recommended at all.

Comment: I mean can i upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 in april? (when 22.04 will be released)

Comment: Yes, there is an upgrade path to 22.04 from 21.10.  It should prompt you to upgrade when it is available.

Comment: Yes... You can... Always upgrade to it when it is released you can run `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Sometimes it is better to wait a bit so they can fix any bugs on a new upgrade, instead of upgrading as soon it comes out.

Comment: It is too early, but if you like adventures - use `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

Comment: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-22-04-lts

Answer (score 3):

Yes you Can!

There are two ways, GUI and CLI.

Open a Terminal and type:

```bsh
sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3
```

[Update Ubuntu GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWi1M.png)

Or you can do it from terminal. I prefer CLI so Open a Terminal and type:

```bsh
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Read all prompt before typing `y`, but you good to go.

Thanks for using Ubuntu :)

This is main Source from [Ubuntu Blog](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today) upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04.

Comment: Currently `apt dist-upgrade && apt autoremove` is also needed to fix some `python 3.9` libraries that were held back in `21.10`

Comment: Since the question is about how to upgrade when 22.04 is released and WWE have now reached that point, could I ask why you have shown the -d flag? I thought that meant upgrade to development version.

Comment: @nickform Apparently `-d` bypasses the staged rollout: "The reason that you need to pass the -d flag is because Ubuntu prefers to prompt users to upgrade some time after the release" https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403527/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-21-10-to-ubuntu-22-04#comment2437643_1403685

Answer (score 1):

Next version of Ubuntu (it's 22.04) will be released in 4/21/2022. After released, you can run (don't type $):

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade -y # Update existing packages to their latest version
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Another way (not suggested):

```
# upgrade your packages first...
# then run:
$ sudo sed -i 's/impish/jammy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
# do again update commands
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Remember to reboot your system after upgraded successfully.

Or you can open Software Updator from Applications menu and let it update existing packages, it may warn you about the new release (you will need to wait it). Do needed steps and your Ubuntu should be upgraded.

Don't install Ubuntu 22.04 Beta now, this can lead to some system problems when they may not fixed yet.

Comment: Hello. You do not know if this information is correct. The 22.04 version has yet to reach RC, things could change.

Comment: Thank you about this, I will fix the post.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to install snap version of firefox it will stall out on it. I had to boot to recovery and fix broken install to finish the process. Good news is that it works with all your files and many setting intact.

1. If fail or blackout reboot computer
2. use appropriate Fn key to boot into grub menu
3. select advance options for ubuntu
4. choose linux kernal option with (recovery mode)
5. choose dpkg option
6. when asked type y and then enter
7. it should continue where you left off
8. after it completes and returns you to menu options select root
9. press enter key and type reboot and press enter key

10.optional from this you can do a sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade

11.this installs more packages from jammy repos and upgrade many apps

12.Firefox is still the issue but it should allow you to boot normally after this when you type reboot and press enter

- make sure to have a ethernet cable plugged in or enable networking for wifi.

Comment: Hello. In what way is this an answer to the question that was asked?