# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 21.10 to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade but i get this below:

[image]

It should be released today 21 April i don't get it?

Comment: Try `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` as it might take some time before the upgrade is moved to production, typically first after 22.04.1 has been released. What has been released now is only the iso for new installs.

Comment: @SorenA One question what does -d do?

Comment: It will install development version, which 22.04 upgrade still will be as I described.

Comment: @SorenA What does development version mean?

Comment: Development or beta version is what comes before production.

Comment: @SorenA If i download the Development version how will it effect the Operating System in the long run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135715/discussion-between-jonte-yh-and-soren-a).

Comment: ISO release is today which is for NEW INSTALLS, the *upgrade* switch won't open till next week (at the earliest)

Comment: It is preferable to copy and paste the terminal output rather than posting a screenshot, so that it is easier to read and easier to find using search.

Comment: Please check it again. Update 22.04 is currently available. For 21.10 :)

Comment: @sohamPatel Thanks now it is working!

Comment: just drop the `-d` from the end of the `sudo do-release -upgrade`and will update but use a development (unstable) version.

Comment: None of the answers below worked for me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

We all have been waiting for the 22.04 version release. The April 21, 2022 is here. It seems the wait is finally over. Not quite!

## Don't try to upgrade the day Ubuntu 22.04 is released

Just wait a week or two. Eventually when you open the **Software Updater** app, it will prompt you to upgrade. Big upgrades like this are rolled out in stages, so that everyone does not try to upgrade at the same time and overload and crash the download servers.

### For upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

The wait is not over yet. LTS release upgrade prompt won't appear until a few weeks after the version 22.04.1 is released in August 2022.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @user68186 i have another question if i download the Development version how will it effect the Operating System until the stable version is available?

Comment: @JonteYH I can't predict how the upgrade to the development version will go. It may work **OR** it may break something. It depends on your exact hardware and software configuration. The longer you wait the chances of everything will work gets better and better as more bugs are reported from real world upgrades and use and are fixed. You may want to keep an eye on this site and the [Ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/) to see what problems others are having.

Comment: On which tags should i click forward on Ubuntu forum?

Comment: In my experience, upgrades have never worked for me. A fresh install works, at the least time and frustration. Case in point: I tried to 'upgrade' my Toshiba laptop from 21 to 22. All seemed to go well: thousands of files downloaded. Rebooted. No update. Debugging could need weeks of time. A fresh install is usually <30 minutes and has never failed me. The frustration point is the download: obtaining an ISO file can take days. Ubuntu needs many more mirror servers, say another thousand.

Answer (score 13):

The [22.04 Release Notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668?_ga=2.174464929.2034962084.1650677682-1415555797.1616660076) have been updated to highlight why standard release upgrades have not been enabled yet:

> **Upgrading from Ubuntu 21.10**
>
> Upgrades to 22.04 LTS are currently not enabled (due [to] a bug with `snapd` and `update-notifier`) but will be in the next couple of days.

One imagines the bug is [LP#1969162](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1969162). After a fix is released, **be patient**. Mirrors need to update. Since it's a bug in 21.10, Phased Updates means some folks won't see it for up to one week. At some point soon, they will make release-upgrades available to 21.10 users.

- Note that 20.04 users are different. You won't see a release-upgrade prompt until August 2022, matching a first point release of 22.04. 20.04 users don't have this bug; the three-month delay for 22.04 to stabilize has been a normal element of LTS-to-LTS release-upgrades for over a decade.

Comment: Do you know if the bug is tracked anywhere on e.g. launchpad to see the progress?

Comment: @Freddy edited the answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Then make sure you have the update-manager-core package installed.

```
sudo apt install update-manager-core
```

After that, run the following command to begin the upgrade process.

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

Then follow the on-screen instruction to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.

I found this here. You can also use this process for other Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
https://itsubuntu.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-22-04-lts/

Comment: this works for me upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04 using the terminal. There are some hiccups on certain apps and internal error from the first boot. However, overall experience is better than 20.04. do take note that snap firefox is slower at launch compared to deb. And if you have multiple extensions on your machine, probably best to wait because many are not supported or "glitchy" as of now.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade after 2weeks from now.
Ubuntu 22.04 is still in development phrase. Which means in-case you go ahead to upgrade this might result to lots of bugs and inconsistencies.

For those who want to contribute to solving and identifying bugs, you can upgrade via: where **-d** implies development.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 has been released, it's not in development phase any longer. The reason that you need to pass the `-d` flag is because Ubuntu prefers to prompt users to upgrade some time after the release. But Ubuntu 22.04 is fully released as you can see in the home page of ubuntu.com [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdAwz.png)

Comment: well thanks for this, I think the article i read mislead me.

Comment: @Flimm, but issuing the command above I get: `Checking for a new Ubuntu release / = Welcome to the Ubuntu 'Jammy Jellyfish' development release = / ''This release is still in development.''`

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:
To the moderators: I have removed the replies to other answers in my post.
I have noticed that my previous answer has been deleted as it was thought to be an upgrading process from 20.04 to 22.04, hence appears not to answer the question. I would like to clarify, that this method **works for upgrading from 21.10 to 22.04 as well**, and is **not specific to 20.04 or upgrading from LTS releases.** I have tested it on my machine running 21.10, and an upgrade to 22.04 was successful. Thank you.

This is caused by a lack of an entry in the changelogs for Jammy 22.04 (here https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release). However, a slight modification of the `impish` URL for release notes will reveal that Jammy has a stable release available for download, albeit not registered yet in the changelogs (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement.html).
From editing the `impish` changelog, we can get this:

```
Dist: jammy
Name: Jammy Jellyfish
Version: 22.04 LTS
Date: Fri, 22 April 2022 02:00:00 UTC
Supported: 1
Description: This is the 22.04 LTS release
Release-File: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/Release
ReleaseNotes: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement
ReleaseNotesHtml: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement.html
UpgradeTool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/jammy.tar.gz
UpgradeToolSignature: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/jammy.tar.gz.gpg
```

The file `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` stores all the URLs to be queried for new releases by `do-release-upgrade`.
We can host a file like this https://github.com/czlucius/ubuntu-upgrade-jammy/blob/main/meta_release_jammy (which is the changelogs on the official website + the 22.04 update) on a public server (you can also host it on GitHub). Feel free to use the one I've hosted here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/czlucius/ubuntu-upgrade-jammy/main/meta_release_jammy.

Change `URI = https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release` to `URI = https://raw.githubusercontent.com/czlucius/ubuntu-upgrade-jammy/main/meta_release_jammy`(or your hosted URL) with an editor such as `nano`.

Run `do-release-upgrade` again, and this time it will pick up the new update of 22.04 and apply it to your system. This will install the production build, and not the development one.

**You can use this method to update from 21.10 to 22.04.**

Note that when you have completed the upgrade, do not forget to change the URL back.

More info: https://github.com/czlucius/ubuntu-upgrade-jammy/ (Disclaimer: this is my GitHub repo)

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Update 22.04 is available, so you can directly do `do-release-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to update from the Brazil server without a success. Many different errors (connection failed, unsupported repositories...).

I changed to an United States server (Software and Updates >> Donwload from >>  Server from United States) and was successful.