# Upgrade Kubuntu 21.10 to Kubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, do-release-upgrade

I have Kubuntu 21.10 installed and want to upgrade to Kubuntu 22.04. Is it already out for upgrades? What tool should I use?

I installed the ubuntu-update-manager, and it seemed to have recognized the new version, but in the info it said it was a development release. Did they forget to update the info, or is it really not the stable release yet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade from Ubuntu 21.10 to Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403527/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-21-10-to-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Yeah. Thank you!