# Ubuntu 20.04 - 21.10 on Lenovo x230

Tags: wireless, lenovo, x230

I am new to Ubuntu and still quite new in using Linux. (I been using Elementary and Mint before). I would like to ask about if it is possible to successfully install (stable) one of the last 2 distribution. I would love if it will be 21.10.

I have x230, i7 - 4 cores, 8GB Ram, 512 Kingstone SSD and modded screen for FHD with Chinese chip.
I tried to install 21.10 and I have a major problem with wifi card (dropping connection) and app store is snapping - not installing, or not showing installed software.

Thanks for help and cheers.
Tomas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)