# LTS or regular release for a CS student

Tags: 22.04, lts, 22.10

I have been an ubuntu user for years, and i am currently a *Computer Science student*, learning coding, networks & it. Do you recommend me to use the 22.04 LTS release, or the latest regular release?

My system is compatible with both releases, but I am not sure if it's better to have the LTS with added PPA's regarding dev tools, or go with the latest release resulting in less added ppa's. I care about new features but i want a reasonably stable system too at the level windows 10 is for an tech savvy user (I refer to that OS just for reference).

Maybe there is no difference for my usage scenario.

Comment: There isn't any definitive answer to this, so I'm afraid it will be based solely on opinion.

Comment: It would be actually great to hear your opinions!

Comment: This site isn't suited for discussing opinions - this is better suited on a discussion forum. 

Comment: At the first place, I was not sure if it's really a matter of opinion, so I will wait for any helpful possible answers. If others agree so, I will ask in the forum, thank you!

Comment: I personally think you'll learn more from using a non-LTS & using the regular *release-upgrade* cycle, given you'll experience & learn more from it....  However it'll also depend on your hardware & software you'll use, as many 3rd party apps are only built for the LTS releases, and likewise some 3rd party kernel modules (aka *drivers*) exist only for LTS releases; thus your specific needs will dictate which is best.  Opinions are off-topic here, as this is **not** a forum, but a Q&A site.  https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the address of Ubuntu Forum(s).

Comment: I suggest you read https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic (*but particularly the don't ask!*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

Comment: All this talk about the "latest", and a few days ago there was someone posting a question asking about running a 12.04 VM because that's what the course used. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -1):

**In any case: if in doubt use an LTS version**

LTS is the safe choice.

- It has longer support time, meaning you are not pushed to upgrade too soon. A non LTS version currently has 9 months support, so you have to follow always the upcoming releases (upgrade in every ~6 months). Till the LTS has long years of support, you can even skip the next LTS if you will. Check out releases and support times here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases
- Also if you later realize you want a newer version you can upgrade to it, the other way around (when you install something newer and you realize you want to go back to the latest LTS ) is not supported.

I would recommend to have an LTS on your main notebook/desktop and you can have any time a virtual machine if you want to try a newer version or missing something from the LTS.