# Which directories should I exclude in a backup if I want to return to an earlier version of Ubuntu

Tags: backup, downgrade

I am currently running Ubuntu Studio 22.10.  I am going to replace my HDD with and SDD.  At the same time, I want to return to Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS.  I recognize that I may not be able to open some files created with newer versions of the applications; I can deal with that.  My bigger question is: which directories (e.g home/snap, home/.mozilla, etc.) should I exclude from the backup to avoid conflicts later.

Comment: Not that it's any of my business, but why do you need to go back? Is Ubuntu Studio 22.10 not secure?

Comment: @Logan I can't speak for Nicked, but this would be my reason. First, I don't think it is a question of security. It is convenience. Non LTS releases like 22.10 reaches end of life in 9 months. That means I have to upgrade to the next release every six months to keep my systems get updates and fixes. An LTS release like 22.04 gets updates for at least 5 years. There is no rush to update to the next LTS which comes out in April of 2024.

Comment: @Logan Also see [What is the difference between a long term support release and a normal release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

Comment: @Logan I agree with above: Ubuntu studio is likely more useful as an LTS. The in between versions probably do not add that much in features and all security related issues will be added to it anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything outside of your `/home/` can be excluded. You can use everything from the backup that is inside `/home`. This will generally work for all releases from and including an LTS up to the next LTS.

And if it does not work it will be a minor issue involving one specific piece of software.

snaps are kept up to date independently of the OS and are cpmpatible as long as the OS is current.